# Azure Logic App Runs history & Trigger history

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

is there a way to get Azure Logic App Runs history & Trigger history through the asp.net core application?

[image]

I have more than 10 logic apps so I need to get all of them Runs history & Trigger history too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`REST API`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggerhistories/get)

> GET
> [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/triggers/{triggerName}/histories/{historyName}?api-version=2016-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/%7BworkflowName%7D/triggers/%7BtriggerName%7D/histories/%7BhistoryName%7D?api-version=2016-06-01)

To get History

> GET
> [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}/actions/{actionName}/requestHistories?api-version=2016-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/%7BworkflowName%7D/runs/%7BrunName%7D/actions/%7BactionName%7D/requestHistories?api-version=2016-06-01)

Comment: this is great really good.is there a way to get all workflows etc... then using my code i can send request